# Changing Input value from component

Tags: angular

Assumign I have the following template expression:

```
<md-input type="number" #power [placeholder]="powerLabel" required>
</md-input>
```

I want to access `power.value` from my component .ts file, how I can do that?

Using ([ngModel]) gave me some console errors I couldn't manage to handle.

Comment: What material framework are you using ?

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if it will work but have you tried creating a member variable using ViewChild like this: `@ViewChild('power') power;`
Then you can handle the value using `this.power.nativeElement.value`
Remember to import ViewChild: `import {ViewChild} from '@angular/core';`